# A Powershell function to convert unix time to string?

Tags: datetime, powershell, ado.net, sqlite, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to read the date fields of Firefox places.sqlite datedase using ADO.NET and PowerShell.

Obviously these fields are in Unix time.

I'm looking for a conversion to .Net datetime or string

**Edit:**
I want to bind the datarow to a WPF GridView.

I need either a way to do the conversion within the SQL query or some way while binding the datarows to the grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should put you on the right path:

```
[TimeZone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($unix))
```

Comment: I accept this answer, because it is the answer to the verbatime question. My problem was a bit different and meanwhile I found the solution

Answer (score 3):

```
[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds(1303743289))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function Convert-UnixTimeToDateTime([int]$UnixTime)
{
    (New-Object DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, [DateTimeKind]::Utc)).AddSeconds($UnixTime)
}
```

This returns an object with the "kind" set to Utc.  Then, if you want local time, call the ToLocalTime method on the resulting object.

Answer (score 2):

The working solution to my problem is

```
SELECT datetime (b.dateAdded / 1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') dateAdded  from moz_bookmarks
```

BTW it is partly hidden in the [the original documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

The other part is that you have to find out, that you must divide the integer by 1000000 to get the seconds.