# How to convert the SSM output & unix time format to system time in powershell to save as csv

Tags: powershell, ssm

I am using a ssm command to describe instance patches, while getting the output the installedtime is in unspecified format, so how to convert it to the format of mm/dd/yy

```
aws ssm describe-instance-patches --instance-id "XXXXXX" --profile "XXXXXX" --region "us-west-2"  --max-results 10 --output table
```

The default output of the ssm command is json

output:

```
|| Classification | InstalledTime | KBId | Severity | State | Title
|| CriticalUpdates | 1476770400.0 | KB3199209 | Unspecified | Installed | Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB3199209)
|| CriticalUpdates | 1479193200.0 | KB3199986 | Unspecified | Installed | Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63226852/edit) your question and show the output as formatted **text** instead of a link to a barely readable image.

Comment: You will need to give some specifications of the date format as e.g. whether the day is prior the month (or not). E.g.: '01-02-2020': **January 2nd** or **February 1st**?

Comment: Downvoted question until image is replaced with output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Powershell function to convert unix time to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779244/a-powershell-function-to-convert-unix-time-to-string) and [PowerShell date format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23616614/1701026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script work like as expected

```
    $instances= aws ssm describe-instance-patches --instance-id "xxxxxxx" --profile "xxxxxxx" --region "us-west-2"  --max-results 50
$pathToOutputFile = "C:\Users\Documents\prod_instance_us_west_2.csv"
$array = ($instances| ConvertFrom-Json) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Patches

$report = @()
foreach($a in $array)
{
    $report += New-Object psobject -Property @{Title=$a.Title;KBId=$a.KBId;Classification=$a.Classification;Severity=$a.Severity;State=$a.State;InstalledTime=[TimeZone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($a.InstalledTime))}
}
$report | export-csv $pathToOutputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update your question with the output instead of an Image.**

The dateformat is not unspecified format, it is Unix format.

To convert from Unix format to a DateTime variable do like this:

```
$oUNIXDate=(Get-Date 01.01.1970)+([System.TimeSpan]::fromseconds(1476770400))
```

I cant test this but you can probably do something like this to convert the output afterwards:

```
aws ssm describe-instance-patches --instance-id "XXXXXX" --profile "XXXXXX" --region "us-west-2"  --max-results 10 --output table | select-object Classification, @{ Name = 'TimeStamp'; Expression = {  ((Get-Date 01.01.1970)+([System.TimeSpan]::fromseconds($_.InstalledTime))) }}, KBId, Severity, State, Title
```

Comment: yes but i want to the out to be converted in powershell while running the SSM command

Comment: @muralitharan unless the aws command contains functionallity to covert the output built in you will need to convert it after using the command.